# Dealing with tuples and bindings

Tags: haskell, tuples

I'm writing a function that sums the elements of a list of tuples like this:

```
sumAll [(2,4,11), (3,1,-5), (10,-3,6)] = (15,2,12)
```

I do have this:

```
sumAll :: (Num a, Num b, Num c) => [(a,b,c)] -> (a,b,c)
sumAll l = (foldr (+) 0 as, foldr (+) 0 bs, foldr (+) 0 cs) 
               where trd (a,b,c) = c
                     as = (map (fst) l) 
                     bs = (map (snd) l)
                     cs = (map (trd) l)
```

However the compiler complains:

```
Couldn't match type `(a, b, c)' with `(b1, b0)'
    Expected type: [(b1, b0)]
      Actual type: [(a, b, c)]
    Relevant bindings include
      as :: [b1] (bound at ficha3.hs:22:22)
      cs :: [c] (bound at ficha3.hs:24:22)
      l :: [(a, b, c)] (bound at ficha3.hs:20:12)
      sumAll :: [(a, b, c)] -> (a, b, c) (bound at ficha3.hs:20:1)
    In the second argument of `map', namely `l'
    In the expression: (map (fst) l)
```

And the same for the expression (map (snd) l).

If I delete 'c' parameters from function definition it Works. 
Like this:

```
sumAll :: (Num a, Num b) => [(a,b)] -> (a,b)
sumAll l = (foldr (+) 0 as, foldr (+) 0 bs) 
               where as = (map (fst) l) 
                     bs = (map (snd) l)
```

My questions, if possible:

1. Why is 'c' "screwing" the output tuple?
2. How can I work this around?

Comment: Style comment: `(map (fst) l)` is more commonly written `map fst l` -- no parentheses needed.

Comment: Uniform tuples are a bit annoying if you want to apply an operation to all elements. If you used lists instead of tuples, you could write `sumAll` simply as `foldr (zipWith (+)) [0, 0 ..] :: Num a => [[a]] -> [a]`. However, the shortest input list would determine the length of the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider how your `fst`, `snd`, and `trd` are defined. If you are using `fst` from `Prelude`, then it has a type of `fst :: (a, b) -> a`, which does not work for 3-tuples.

Comment: Functions fst and snd redefined. Thank you!